# How to make options mandatory in KSH script

Tags: ksh, options

Here is the skeleton to catch arguments in my script :

```
# fMain(){

        while getopts "d:e:h" _OPTION; do
                case $_OPTION in
                d)                              
                        dateVal=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                e)
                        extensionVal=$OPTARG
                        fListArgument "OPN_BYPASS" $OPTARG
                        ;;
                h)
                        fToonHelp
                        ;;
                \?)     echo "Please run '$0 -h' for help"
                        vARG_VLAG="Y"
                        ;;
                esac
        done

        exit 0
```

How can I set the options d and e mandatory ? I could simply throw an error if they are not filled (using a binary variable to see if they are filled or not). But I guess, a more convenient way to do this exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ -z "$dateVal" ]; then
           printf "Option -d must be specified\n"
           exit
fi
if [ -z "$extensionVal" ]; then
           printf "Option -e must be specified\n"
           exit
fi
```